# Memcmp и Seg Fault

Tags: c, неопределённое-поведение

Задаю нулевые строки и выполняю memcmp:

```
char *str1 = NULL;
char *str2 = NULL;
memcmp(str1, str2, 2);
```

Почему, если число будет нечётным, то он выдаст сегу (ну что по идее всегда и должно быть). А если чётное, то сеги нет??...
По идее должно же работать либо всегда с сегой, если в функции нет проверки на NULL, либо всегда без сеги, если она есть.

Но почему вот так?

Comment: [The behavior is undefined if access occurs beyond the end of either object pointed to by lhs and rhs.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) [undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Comment: Странно это, у меня под GNU C++11 и memcmp(str1, str2, 2) и memcmp(str1, str2, 3) - ошибка при выполнении

Comment: Запустил на онлайн компиляторе. Там вообще нет ошибки никогда.

Comment: Ну и надо было в вопросе написать - на online компиляторе

Answer (score 1):

Нулевая строка — это `""`, а `NULL` — это нулевой указатель :).

Что до UB... Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени. А у кого-то будет десять метров размазанного по асфальту мяса сразу.

Вот из описания данной функции: [*If the objects overlap, the behavior is undefined.

If either dest or src is an invalid or **null pointer**, the **behavior is undefined**, even if count is zero.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).
Вопрос на этом закрыт?